# Result of 100 concurrent threads, each incrementing variable to 100

Tags: multithreading, concurrency

I'm writing to ask about this question from 'The Little Book of Semaphores' by Allen B. Downey.

[Question from 'The Little Book of Semaphores'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UgZw.png)

> Puzzle: Suppose that 100 threads run the following program concurrently. (if you are not familiar with Python, the `for` loop runs the update 100 times.):
>
> ```python
> for i in range(100):
>    temp = count
>    count = temp + 1
> ```
>
> What is the largest possible value of `count` after all threads have completed? What is the smallest possible value? Hint: the first question is easy; the second is not.

My understanding is that `count` is a variable shared by all threads, and that it's initial value is 0.
I believe that the largest possible value is 10,000, which occurs when there is no interleaving between threads.

I believe that the smallest possible value is 100. If line 2 is executed for each thread, they will each have a value of `temp = 0`. If line 3 is then executed for each thread, they will each set `count = 1`. If the same behaviour occurs in each iteration, the final value of `count` will be 100.

Is this correct, or is there another execution path that can result in a value smaller than 100 for `count`?

Comment: The largest value is indeed 10,000. I think for the smallest value, it depends on how you are accessing the `count` variable. If you are accessing it through any sort of atomic memory ordering, then yes, the smallest value you can see is 100. If you are just issuing a plain read/write, It is possible for the `count` variable to be cached in a register, so it effectively never gets updated.

Comment: I think the final `count` could be as small as 2. (I'm not saying I'd expect it to ever happen in anybody's lifetime. Only saying that it's _possible._) I'll post my reasoning as an answer some time later on. I don't want to spoil the fun for anybody who wants to solve it on their own just yet.

Comment: Yes Soloman, I tried figuring out some execution order where 1 thread maintains a value of 0 right until the very last iteration, but I couldn't figure it out. It will probably be productive to simplify the problem to 5 threads counting to 10, or something like that. I'll give it some thought too.

Comment: In my worst-case scenario (where the final `count` equals 2), there is a thread A, and a thread B, and then there's all the rest. Thread A has to be the first thread to read `count`, and then all the rest have to run to completion before threads A and B do a few final things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The worst case that I can think of will leave `count` equal to two. It's extremely unlikely that this would ever happen in practice, but in theory, it's possible. I'll need to talk about Thread A, Thread B, and 98 other threads:

1. Thread A reads `count` as zero, but then it is preempted before it can do anything else,
2. Thread B is allowed to run 99 iterations of its loop, and 98 other threads all run to completion before thread A finally is allowed to run again,
3. Thread A writes 1 to `count` before—are you ready to believe this?—it gets preempted *again!*
4. Thread B starts its 100th iteration. It gets as far as reading `count` as 1 (just now written by thread A) before thread A finally comes roaring back to life and runs to completion,
5. Thread B is last to cross the finish line after it writes 2 to `count`.

Comment: Very well explained.